# How to use solution of NSolve as a list and them plot?

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, equation-solving

I am solving a set of equations with one of the parameters Rload as a list.  After I solve it, how do I calculate power of each Rload using the formula power=(X-Y)*Rload, and then plot power vs Rload?

```
NSolve[{-(310 - X)/0.1 + (X - Y)/20 + 0.09128^2*X*(X - Y)/(5 + Rload) - 
0.5*0.09128^2*Rload*(X - Y)^2/(5 + Rload)^2 == 0, 
(Y - 300)/10 - (X - Y)/20 - 0.09128^2*Y*(X - Y)/(5 + Rload) - 
0.5*0.09128^2*Rload*(X - Y)^2/(5 + Rload)^2 == 0, Rload > 0}, {X, Y}]

Rload = Range[1, 20, 1];
values = Tuples[{Rload}];
{#, sol[Sequence @@ #]} & /@ values // Flatten[#, 1] &

(* power[Rload]=(X-Y)*Rload *)
(* Plot[power[Rload], {Rload,1,20}]  *)
```

Comment: Are you trying to obtain `NSolve` output for all `Rload` in the range of 1 to 20?  If so, use `Table`.  I do not understand the second block of code, and `sol` is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

I have additionally assumed that `X > 0` and `Y > 0`

```
eqns = {
   -(310 - X)/0.1 + (X - Y)/20 + 0.09128^2*X*(X - Y)/(5 + Rload) - 
     0.5*0.09128^2*Rload*(X - Y)^2/(5 + Rload)^2 == 0,
   (Y - 300)/10 - (X - Y)/20 - 0.09128^2*Y*(X - Y)/(5 + Rload) - 
     0.5*0.09128^2*Rload*(X - Y)^2/(5 + Rload)^2 == 0,
   Rload > 0, X > 0, Y > 0}// Rationalize[#, 0] &;

sol = NSolve[eqns, {X, Y}];

Length@sol

(* 2 *)
```

The two solutions cover different segments of the range of `Rload`

```
Plot[Evaluate[(X - Y)*Rload /. sol], {Rload, 0, 20},
 Frame -> True,
 FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {Rload, Power}),
 PlotLegends -> Placed[Automatic, {.8, .3}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you!  It works.  Do you know why the solution is separated in 2 segments?

Comment: Because the solution has multiple complex branches and the real result switches between the branches.

Answer (score 0):

> After I solve it, how do I calculate power of each Rload ...

```
r = Range[1, 20, 1]
```

Let's say you have solved and have {r,x,y} as a list of 3-tuples called `vals`, then:

```
vals={{1, 309.918, 308.202}, {2, 309.92, 308.001}, {3, 309.922, 
  307.815}, {4, 309.923, 307.644}, {5, 309.925, 307.485}, {6, 309.926,
   307.337}, {7, 309.928, 307.199}, {8, 309.929, 307.071}, {9, 309.93,
   306.95}, {10, 309.931, 306.838}, {11, 309.933, 306.732}, {12, 
  309.934, 306.632}, {13, 309.934, 306.538}, {14, 309.935, 
  306.449}, {15, 309.936, 306.364}, {16, 309.937, 306.285}, {17, 
  309.938, 306.209}, {18, 309.939, 306.137}, {19, 309.939, 
  306.069}, {20, 309.94, 306.003}};
```

use a pure function to create `{r,power}` pairs.

```
power = {#[[1]], #[[1]] (#[[2]] - #[[3]])} & /@ vals
```

> ```
> {{1, 1.71529}, {2, 3.83787}, {3, 6.31944}, {4, 9.119}, {5, 
>   12.2016}, {6, 15.5371}, {7, 19.0997}, {8, 22.8667}, {9, 
>   26.8185}, {10, 30.938}, {11, 35.2099}, {12, 39.6209}, {13, 
>   44.1591}, {14, 48.8139}, {15, 53.5761}, {16, 58.437}, {17, 
>   63.3893}, {18, 68.4259}, {19, 73.5408}, {20, 78.7284}}
> ```

```
ListLinePlot[power
 , Frame -> True
 , GridLines -> Automatic
 , FrameLabel -> {"Rload", "Power"}
 , Mesh -> All
 , MeshStyle -> {AbsolutePointSize[6], Red}
 , PlotStyle -> {Thin, Black}
 ]
```

[image]